# Loading DLL results in error 193, even though it can load in both ctypes and JNA

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm porting a Python program to C++ (on Windows). Since said code depends on a DLL, I need to load the DLL. But, when I call `LoadLibraryA` specifying the full path of my DLL (with backslashes), it fails to load and `GetLastError` returns 193.

Here's a sample program to demonstrate:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "You only need to specify one argument, path to DLL." << endl;
    exit(2);
  }

  HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryA(argv[1]);
  if (dll == NULL) {
    cout << "DLL at " << argv[1] << " could not be loaded." << endl;
  }
  FreeLibrary(dll);
  return 0;
}
```

I specified the full path to my DLL (like "C:\path\to\somewhere\test.dll") as the first command line argument, and it fails. Why won't it load, even though it does in foreign function interfaces like JNA and ctypes?

Edit 1: The DLL is 64-bit.

Comment: Mixing 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: Are your dll and executable built for the same architecture?

Comment: [Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) 193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`, "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easy way to check if you're compiling 64-bit or 32-bit code is to use the following code (C++17):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cout << "Your compiler compiled for " << sizeof(void*) * 8 << "-bit systems." << endl;
}
```

The code above works by checking the size of a pointer. 32-bit applications use 4-byte pointers, while 64-bit applications use 8-byte pointers.

**EDIT:** You can check using `dumpbin` (available with Visual Studio). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows). You can also use preprocessor macros:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  #ifdef __MINGW64__
  cout << "MinGW-w64" << endl;
  #endif
}
```

This will only print `"MinGW-w64"` if it is compiled by MinGW-w64. These methods are far more reliable than the pointer method I originally used.

In my case, I was using **MinGW** and not **MinGW-w64**. Hence, the resulting `.exe` was a 32-bit application, which clashed with the 64-bit `.dll`, which in turn caused error 193.

Comment: `#ifdef __MINGW64__` .  See https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/

Comment: A convoluted (and brittle) way to do what [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) does for you already.

Comment: answer was edited a month ago, as per comments